# How is the entropy of the universe defined?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, cosmology

My understanding is that to define the entropy of a system what you have to do is as follows:

1. Define the boundaries of your system.
2. Define a set of "microstates" of the system.
3. Define a partition of microstates of the system where each element of the partition is measurable and known as a "macrostate".

The entropy of the system in some macrostate A is the logarithm of the measure of the microstates contained in mactrostate A.

Now, I often hear cosmologists say things like "the entropy of the early universe was low." What I understand that to mean is that for some specific partition of the microstates of the universe P, the state of the early universe was contained in some "small" element of that partition.

What I am trying to know is: What is this partition P which is being implicitly referred to? (And optionally, what is special about that partition which allows us to not be explicit about it?)

Comment: Well what macrostates do you usually see defined for systems? Is there any reason you think they cannot be applied to systems as large as the universe? (I am not saying whether or not I think it would be valid, I just think it would be helpful to know what you know and have thought through so far).

Comment: Usually, either amount of energy, or distribution of energy or distribution of mass or distributions of different kinds of matter. I think all can apply, but they don't say the same thing about a system. For instance, I could have really high entropy wrt spacial distribution of mass and really low entropy wrt distribution of energy among ptcls in my system. (Say, a single ptcl has all the energy and all the others are spread uniformly throughout space)

Comment: Ok. And why do you think these do not apply to the universe? You always have to specify the macrostates you are looking at regardless of the scale of the system in question. Right?

Comment: Right. But I often hear cosmologists say things like "the early universe had low entropy" without stating what the macrostates are. So, what macrostates are they talking about?

Comment: I understand the above apply. My question is, "when someone just says 'the entropy of the universe'" which macrostates are they talking about?"

Comment: Don't be quick to take what scientists say concerning the issue of entropy at the beginning, simply because it doesn't make sense. It breaks the third law, in that a system cannot both be in a high temperature, low-entropy state. In fact, this generated cold big bang theories, which for some reason, hasn't taken on, despite the standard model problems.

Comment: @GarethMeredith That's not what the third law of thermodynamics says. The third law of thermodynamics says that a perfect crystal at absolute zero has zero entropy.

Comment: I beg to differ, I've been writing on the subject for a while. When you take a system, an ordinary system, towards absolute zero, its entropy also tends to vanish. As I said, a hot big bang with a low entropy doesn't make sense, there are no systems we can theoretically or experimentally infer to support that such a state can exist. If you take the third law seriously as I do, then this is pretty much obvious. As I also said, this led to motivation in cold big bang theories.

Comment: In fact, I shouldn't even need to add this, but for clarity, the third law is about ground state systems where no motion happens. This is also impossible for experimental reasons. All we can infer from the third law, is an approximation in which there exists a relationship between cooling a system and the ability to reduce entropy as a result.

Comment: @GarethMeredith the temperature of a system doesn't directly determine it's entropy.

Comment: This isn't entirely true, since the theory of any transmissible energy is through motion and this is related to the entropy. However, its not so simple, the zero point energy field is a ground state motion, so in a sense, you can never reach zero point fields. The fact is, is that temperature is dependent on the definition of entropy. Some have claimed you can argue there is some ''derivative'' of the entropy existing when temperature is not there, but since physics says otherwise experimentally, I tend not to think about it.